# Deploying asp.net application in IIS 6.0

Tags: asp.net

I am getting user name by using the following code:

`txtName.Text = Environment.UserName;`

I have deployed the code in IIS and while running the application then i am getting 
user name as "NETWORK SERVICE" in the textbox instead of logged user name.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is your question? What does it have to do with Deploying the app?

Answer (score 1):

`Environment.UserName` is the name of the user under which the IIS application is running. by default this is the NETWORK SERVICE user. If you want the username of the user who is logged in via forms authentication you should look at the [`Page.User` object](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.user.aspx).